# ng2-dragula setOptions and drop version problem

Tags: angular, ng2-dragula

Apparently 1.5.0 support `this.dragulaService.setOptions` while 2.1.1 doesn't and in reverse while 2.1.1 support `this.dragulaService.drop` subscribe 1.5.0 doesn't.

[Stackblitz Fork for 1.5.0](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-dragula-base-rbfvbg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

[Stackblitz Fork for 2.1.1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-dragula-base-yabai4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Relevant code to notice:

1.5.0 (not working)

[(Error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AjqF.png):

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type
>   'EvenEmitter' has no compatible call signatures. (property)
>   AppComponent.dragulaService: DragulaService

```
this.dragulaService.drop("dnd")
      .subscribe(({ name, el, target, source, sibling }) => {
      //content
}
```

1.5.0 (working)

```
this.dragulaService.setOptions('dnd', {
  moves: (el, source, handle, sibling) => !el.classList.contains('nodrag')
});
```

2.1.1 (working)

```
this.dragulaService.drop("dnd")
    .subscribe(({ name, el, target, source, sibling }) => {
    //content
}
```

2.1.1 (not working)

```
this.dragulaService.createGroup("dnd", {
  moves: (el, source, handle, sibling) => !el.classList.contains('nodrag')
});
```

[(Error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN3PS.png):

> Argument of type '{moves: (el: any, source: any, handle: any, sibling:
>   any) => boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'DragulaOptions'. Object literal may only specify known
>   properties, and 'moves' does not exist in type 'Dragula Options'.
>   (parameter) handle: any

Note while there is a [migration guide](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula/blob/master/MIGRATION-v2.md) and [changelog](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula/blob/master/modules/ng2-dragula/CHANGELOG.md) it does [state](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula/blob/master/MIGRATION-v2.md#4-replace-setoptions-and-dragulaoptions-with-dragulaservicecreategroup) [how to replace the setOptions into create group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLD2B.png). But it's still not working in my case.

Is there any way to use both functions? Or do I miss something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want: create group & use drop functionality together?

We use `createGroup` together with `drop` but with one small difference - drop services is added inside Subscription, but I don't think this has any matters. So our code is here:

```
export class xxxComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    public dragula$: Subscription;
    ...

    constructor(public dragulaService: DragulaService) {
        this.dragulaService.createGroup('ITEMS', {
            direction: 'vertical',
            moves: (el, source, handle): boolean => handle.className.indexOf('item-keeper') > -1
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dragula$.add(this.dragulaService.drop('ITEMS')
            .subscribe(({name, el}) => {
                ....
            })
        );
    }

}
```

I think that our solutions is correct in according with documentation about events:
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula#events

Finally I think that your problem is an error with class name because everything else works perfectly on you Stackblitz example. If you uncomment:

```
    this.dragulaService.createGroup("dnd", {
      moves: (el, source, handle, sibling) => !el.classList.contains('nodrag')
    });
```

your labels are not draggable so you get what you need.

Comment: I'm not sure why but when I tried according to docs and uncomment as you said it wasn't the class name error apparently but as you can see in [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN3PS.png): "Argument of type '{moves: (el: any, source: any, handle: any, sibling: any) => boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DragulaOptions<any>'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'moves' does not exist in type 'Dragula Options<any>'. (parameter) handle: any"

Comment: OK - but this is not a code error but lack od @type error. I saw this error on Stackblitz but it work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me.

import these dependencies.

```js
import { DragulaService } from 'ng2-dragula';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
```

.ts file -

```js
MANY_ITEMS = 'MANY_ITEMS';
subs = new Subscription();

  constructor(private dragula: DragulaService) { 

    this.subs.add(dragula.dropModel(this.MANY_ITEMS)
      .subscribe(({ el, target, source, sourceModel, targetModel, item }) => {

        console.log(el, target, source, sourceModel, targetModel, item);

      })
    );
  }
```

.html file -

```html
<ul [(dragulaModel)]='arrayList' [dragula]="MANY_ITEMS">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

you will be able to drag the 'one' and 'two' list items.