# ng2-dragula drop container issue

Tags: angular, ng2-dragula

Follow up question from [ng2-dragula setOptions and drop version problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54742868/ng2-dragula-setoptions-and-drop-version-problem).

Currently, I'm using a placeholder to cheat my way out of the empty container. I believe what I'm doing [currently](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-dragula-base-tn7yky?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) is wrong which is declaring `dragula` and `[(dragulaModel)]` in both the content and container.

As you probably notice in [fork of my another question demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-dragula-base-yn9wdp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) the container was able to be dropable anywhere in the container. While in the [current fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-dragula-base-yabai4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) it's not working like that.

The difference lay in the input checkbox which I add in the html file. What I tried to achieve is something like [this](https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/) which had a `<input>` inside the draggable content.

Is there any issue which prevents it to work like intended? Or did I do something wrong while being unaware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well your issue, the only thing you need is a height for the empty container (it comes from the class at the first example).
so if you have a height you can drop into to the target container.
I hope it makes sense.
changes:

```
<div id="target" dragula="dnd" [(dragulaModel)]="target" style="height:50px">
```